# codeigniter2, nusoap, soap server and examples

Tags: soap, codeigniter-2, nusoap

A morning of googling I've learnt a few things.
Many people would like to use their CI2 installs to make a soap server for other apps to talk to their app.
However, each forum post I find ends in 'This doesn't work in CI2' or similar.

I've found this article:
http://phpmaster.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/

Which is GREAT... but I can't get it working in CI2.

I've put my library in place, renamed where needed and this code is bringing up many errors.
I've not started on the client side yet.

`class soap extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct ()
{
    parent:: __construct ();
    $this->load->library('nusoap_base');
}

function index()
{
    $this->nusoap = new soap_server();
    $this->nusoap->register("getProd");
    $this->nusoap->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
}

function getProd($category) {
    if ($category == "books") {
        return join(",", array(
            "The WordPress Anthology",
            "PHP Master: Write Cutting Edge Code",
            "Build Your Own Website the Right Way"));
    }
    else {
            return "No products listed under that category";
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got fed up, using CI REST library instead (cheers Phil!)
 :)